# Why does databinding not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a car-class like this:

```
public class car
{
    public String Name {get; private set;}

    public car(string name)
    {
      this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

I also have a userControl:

```
public partial class CarListItem : UserControl
{
    private Car car;

    public CarListItem (Car car)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.car= car;
    }

}
```

With xaml:

```
<Grid>
     <Label Content="{Binding Path=car.Name}" Name="lblCarName"/>
</Grid>
```

but the databinding does not work. What am I doing wrong?

I want to show the name of the car on the userControl.

Comment: Do you actually set a name anywhere?

Comment: When I create a car, I set the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to preface the binding expression with car...

```
<Grid>
     <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Name="lblCarName"/>
</Grid>
```

...in addition you need to set the `DataContext` of your `UserControl`

```
public partial class CarListItem : UserControl
{
    public CarListItem (Car car)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = car;
    }
}
```

Also my assumption is that you are passing a name in to the ctor of car other then an empty string or null.

Comment: Bad practise setting the `DataContext` of a `UserControl` from code (it's overridden if I do `<CarListItem DataContext="xyz" ...` in xaml, for starters).

Comment: @Dan: Hey Dude, this guy (OP) needs basic understanding first. He has to learn enough to discuss and even consider best practices.

Comment: @Dan Don't agree, posted explanation on your answer

Answer (score 1):

For a binding to work, you need to have a value in a `Control`'s DataContext property. It can also be inherited. So, child controls can also access parent's `DataContext` if they don't have one.

Properties (not even public) do not help with binding unless used with `Self Binding`.

To make your code work,

Replace

```
this.car = car;
```

With

```
this.DataContext = car;
```

And Replace

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=car.Name}" Name="lblCarName"/>
```

With

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Name="lblCarName"/>
```

Comment: Using the control's `DataContext` in this way is fragile and easily broken.  You should hide this deeper in the control's template or use alternatives.  My answer suggests a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding binds to the datacontext's `car.Name`. In your case, the DataContext is NULL.

You have several options:

1. Set the data context to the `CarListItem` instance
2. Specify binding source.

The first option is usually better.

Even better idea would be to define a `DataTemplate` for your `Car`, and use a list of `Car`s instead of explicit `CarListItem`s:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now, you can use this template as `ItemTemplate` in the list.

Comment: Using the control's `DataContext` in this way is fragile and easily broken.  You should hide this deeper in the control's template or use alternatives.  My answer suggests a more robust solution.  (Also, I voted before your edit.)

Comment: @Dan: the data context should represent logically the view model. it's not really important where exactly the data context is set, as long as it is set correctly. don't see how either of my propositions is not robust. _The_ way of specifying the view model is through data context. keeping the data context merged with the view (like you propose) is a bad design, since it doesn't separate the content and the presentation.

Answer (score -1):

Using `this.DataContext` will *work*, but it's fragile and horrible and not a good way to design your application.  If I were to consume your user control and write this xaml:

```
<CarListItem DataContext="{Binding MyThing}" />
```

... then your control will break, regardless of whether the `Car` property is correctly set or not.  That's not very pretty.

A more robust approach is to mark your `UserControl` element in Xaml with an `x:Name`, and use `ElementName` in your binding.  So, your control looks something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Name="control" ....... (namespaces/etc here)>
  <Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Car.Name, ElementName=control}" Name="lblCarName"/>
  </Grid>
```

Now, if you want to set `DataContext` on the `Grid` (using `DataContext="{Binding Car, ElementName=control}"`), you can get the benefit of datacontext in a more robust way.

However, for any of this to work, you need to be exposing your `car` field as a property, rather than just as a field.  You also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that the UI realises when you change the value of the property, though you can work around this temporarily by setting `car` *before* you call `InitializeComponent()` in your constructor.

Comment: Now, I don't understand where you got that `UserControl` tag from. The `XAML` in question is part of the UserControl. I appreciate your concerns regarding robustness of code, but your code just plainly confuses and misleads. Using a property to expose data from a Control is plain wrong practice. You should always use `Model` to expose data for binding. But, here that is not the point. The guy is getting confused with `DataContext` and public properties and not with what the best practices are.

Comment: The `<UserControl` tag is standard root elment in the xaml of a user control (it'll likely be the parent element of the `Grid` quoted in the question).  I do appreciate what you're saying (and if I had more time I could make my answer more detailed), but I don't agree with teaching bad practises.  I'd downvote answers that suggest using datacontext for these problems the same way as most people would downvote other answers that any bad practise (such global variables, etc that cause as many problems as they solve).

Comment: I'm really confused by your example too.  Are you saying that when I create a user control, the best practice is to name the top-level element and, within the control, use that name and not the data context as the binding source?  That's what it seems you're saying, and I've not only never done that, I've never seen anyone do that.  So:  Why?

Comment: -1 Setting the DataContext in the ctor is common place, specifically when making use of an IoC. This is very frequent within the View in an MVVM setup and is not bad practice as you state. In addition naming your UserControl is very static and there is no real reason to do this. If you are having to name your UserControl your problems might lay elsewhere. Finally, the OP does NOT need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for simplistic binding to occur and the name of the car to appear within the UserControl as the OP requested.